# Windows Phone 7\Silverlight SSH or Telnet library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ssh, libraries

Searching for some telnet or SSH libraries (C#) to using with Windows Phone 7.

At now moment I'm failed convert C# libraries like SharpSSH or Granados.

What existing libraries suatable for Windows Phone 7 or ideas how to convert SharpSSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems such library (in development) found - http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ (with version in development process for Windows Phone 7)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7 doesn't provide socket support needed for such components to work. In our SecureBlackbox (which includes SSH client and server and has Windows Phone 7 version) we implemented Socket adapter class, which can be used for sending data over custom channels. If you can tunnel the data the way you need, then you can use our components. Until WP7 has support for sockets, there's no other option.

Comment: Mango has support for sockets.

Comment: And I'm use same idea in my test ssh app (using my server's daemon and WP7 client to connect to SSH servers)

Comment: @m0rg0t yes, only when Mango is released and deployed to customer devices (I am wondering if all devices get an upgrade).

Comment: As told before, allWP7 devices will get update (developers already can use Mango on devices)